# Bind button text on window Form Dynamically from database

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

How can I bind the `button` text on form dynamically?

I want to give the user a feature where he can change the button text dynamically from the database.

So, from database, I am getting value as a `dataset` [image: <code>Dataset</code> where I am getting value]

Now the problem is, how can I bind this text to my button control on my form.

Can you please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your button? What code have you tried?

Comment: You wanna change the `Name` property of some button to whatever user types?

Comment: I want to display the text of that is coming form db Like bttnSpokeToPeson will display the correcsponding value that is coming event text of that `Spoke to Person and they will call Back'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your Dataset to DataTable and use the below code . I have tested this code according to your question.

```
DataTable _ds = _commonDAC.GetButtonName(1); // i assume you are getting dataset form here 


            foreach (DataRow row in _ds.Rows)
            {
                string ControlName = row["ControlName"].ToString();
                if( ControlName == "bttnLeftMessageOnMachine")
                     bttnLeftMessageOnMachine.Text = row["EventText"].ToString();
                if (ControlName == "bttnSpokeToPerson")
                    bttnSpokeToPerson.Text = row["EventText"].ToString();
                if (ControlName == "bttnHomeKitchenNotReady")
                    bttnHomeKitchenNotReady.Text = row["EventText"].ToString();
                if (ControlName == "bttnInstallerNotReady")
                    bttnInstallerNotReady.Text = row["EventText"].ToString();
                if (ControlName == "bttnNoAnswer")
                    bttnNoAnswer.Text = row["EventText"].ToString();
                if (ControlName == "bttnBusyPhoneLine")
                    bttnBusyPhoneLine.Text = row["EventText"].ToString();
                if (ControlName == "bttnPhLineNotOperation")
                    bttnPhLineNotOperation.Text = row["EventText"].ToString();
                if (ControlName == "bttnCustomerWillCallInstaller")
                    bttnCustomerWillCallInstaller.Text = row["EventText"].ToString();
                if (ControlName == "bttnIncorrectPhNo")
                    bttnIncorrectPhNo.Text = row["EventText"].ToString();
                if (ControlName == "bttnOrderOnHold")
                    bttnOrderOnHold.Text = row["EventText"].ToString();
                if (ControlName == "bttnOtherNoteRequired")
                    bttnOtherNoteRequired.Text = row["EventText"].ToString();
              }
```

Comment: how to convert dataset to datatable

Comment: use this code to do that i think you are getting data like this and   ` DataSet  _ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);
                  DataTable  _dt = _ds.Tables[0];`